# Prevent Pasting in Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

When I try to validating value with RegEX which is only allowing decimal numbers.(Numbers + Perion(.)).
Here is my JS RegEX:

```
let numbers = value.replace(/[^0-9]+(\.[0-9]+{0,5}+)?/g, "");
```

It is giving me this Error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /[^0-9]*(\.[0-9]+{0,5})?/: Nothing to repeat
```

I tried to figured out where I am getting wrong but could not able to find the issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this

Html code:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="fieldname" name="Fieldname" >
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = () => { const myInput = document.getElementById('fieldname'); myInput.onpaste = e => e.preventDefault(); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help but I used the oninput and IsNan on JS side using parseFlot and parseInt to verify and it's working